# Javascript not accepting my function arguments?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i am passing the class and id of chechboxes to the js function and try to make it dynamic to work for id and class of any checkbox to check all and uncheck all check boxes
 here is the html

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="reply_status[]" <?=$checked;?>  class="memebers" value="<?=$status[$e]['mail_sent_id']?>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="send_invoice[]" <?=$checked_send_invoice;?>  class="send_invoice" value="<?=$status[$e]['mail_sent_id']?>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_paid[]" <?=$checked_invoice_paid;?>  class="invoice_paid" value="<?=$status[$e]['mail_sent_id']?>">
            </td>

<td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="check_all_re" name="check_all" onclick="checkall_members('memebers','check_all_re')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Check All
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check_all_sv" name="check_all" onclick="checkall_members('send_invoice','check_all_sv')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Check All
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check_all_ip" name="check_all" onclick="checkall_members('invoice_paid','check_all_ip')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Check All
            </td>
```

and here is the js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkall_members(chechboxclass, chechboxid) {
    // var id = document.getElementById("check_all");
    alert();
    chechboxid = $('#' + chechboxid);
    chechboxclass = $('.' + chechboxclass);
    if (chechboxid.checked) {
        chechboxclass.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    else {
        chechboxclass.removeAttr('checked');
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do, what does it do, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Do **not** use `.attr()` to set the checked state. use `.prop('checked', true_or_false)`. Also, to *get* the state you use `.prop('checked')` - jQuery objects do not have a `.checked` property.

Comment: Can you add your javascript code that binds check all_members to actions on the page? If it is not binded to an action, what actually calls the function?

Comment: Do not use inline event handlers add them with jQuery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have sorted out the simplest solution for my problem that is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function checkall_members(chechboxclass, chechboxid) {

    var checkbox = document.getElementById(chechboxid);
    chechboxclass = $('.' + chechboxclass);

    if (checkbox.checked) {
        chechboxclass.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    else {

        chechboxclass.removeAttr('checked');
    }
}
 </script>
```

i have to get the id elememt within same library of javascript thats why it was not working 
 var checkbox = document.getElementById(chechboxid); 
thanks guys for helping me

Answer (score 3):

Replace your if..else block with the following.

```
chechboxclass.prop('checked', chechboxid.prop('checked'));
```

By the way, it's *checkbox* and not *chec**h**box*.

To improve your code even more, get rid of the inline events:

```
$('input[name="check_all"]').on('change', function() {
    $($(this).data('toggleAll')).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Now you just need to add `data-toggle-all=".send_invoice"` etc. to those checkboxes. The param value should be the selector of the checkboxes you want to toggle with that checkbox.

If you have all the `name="check_all"` elements a `class`, you could also speed up the selector by using `input.whatever_class` instead of `input[name="check_all"]`